# Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Id @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue int]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp-tags

This my Eror in JSP page

```
    Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${c.catId}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:208)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToNumberConverterFactory$StringToNumber.convert(StringToNumberConverterFactory.java:62)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToNumberConverterFactory$StringToNumber.convert(StringToNumberConverterFactory.java:49)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterFactoryAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:436)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:37)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:203)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter.setAsText(ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectedValueComparator.exhaustiveCompare(SelectedValueComparator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectedValueComparator.isSelected(SelectedValueComparator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag.isSelected(OptionTag.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag.renderOption(OptionTag.java:202)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag.renderFromBodyContent(OptionTag.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.doEndTag(AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.java:66)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.ProductForm_jsp._jspService(ProductForm_jsp.java:333)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 03, 2017 2:06:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/frontend] threw exception [org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Id @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue int] for value '${c.catId}'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${c.catId}"] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${c.catId}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:208)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToNumberConverterFactory$StringToNumber.convert(StringToNumberConverterFactory.java:62)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToNumberConverterFactory$StringToNumber.convert(StringToNumberConverterFactory.java:49)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterFactoryAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:436)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:37)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:203)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter.setAsText(ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectedValueComparator.exhaustiveCompare(SelectedValueComparator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectedValueComparator.isSelected(SelectedValueComparator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag.isSelected(OptionTag.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag.renderOption(OptionTag.java:202)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag.renderFromBodyContent(OptionTag.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.doEndTag(AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.java:66)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.ProductForm_jsp._jspService(ProductForm_jsp.java:333)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my product form where I'am clicking on sell on fasgen

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="a" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Product Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="Header.jsp"></jsp:include>
<!-- Product insertion -->
<%-- <a:url var="url" value='/saveproduct' /> --%>
<%-- <spring:url value='/saveproduct' var="url"/> --%>
<form:form action="saveproduct" commandName="product">
<div class="form-group">
<form:hidden path="pid" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Enter Model Details:
<form:input path="modelDetails" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Enter Product Name:
<form:input path="productname" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Enter Price:
<form:input path="price" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Enter Quantity:
<form:input path="qty" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Enter Patter:
<form:input path="pattern" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Enter Style Type:
<form:input path="styleType" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Enter Wear Type
<form:input path="weartype" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Enter Style Code:
<form:input path="styleCode" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Enter Colour:
<form:input path="color" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Enter Fabric Care:
<form:input path="fabriccare" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Type:
<form:input path="type" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Sleeve:
<form:input path="sleeve" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Enter Neck Type:
<form:input path="necktype" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Enter Pockets:
<form:input path="pockets" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Enter Pockets:
<form:input path="price" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
Ideal For:
<form:select path="category.catId">
<a:forEach items="${categories} " var="c"  >
<form:option value="${c.catId}">${c.idealfor }</form:option>
</a:forEach>
</form:select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="submit" value="Add Product">
</div>
</form:form>

<jsp:include page="Footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller for product

```
package com.project.controllers;

import java.util.List;

//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.project.service.ProductService;
import com.project.model.Category;
//import com.project.service.ProductServiceImpl;
import com.project.model.Product;

@Controller
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;
    @RequestMapping(value="/ProductForm")
    public String productForm(Model model) {
        List<Category> categories=productService.getAllCategory();
        model.addAttribute("categories",categories);
        model.addAttribute("product", new Product());
        System.out.println(categories);
        return "ProductForm";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/saveproduct")
    public String saveProduct(@ModelAttribute(name="product") Product product,BindingResult result){
        productService.addProduct(product);
        return "Home";
    }

}
```

and this my model

```
    package com.project.model;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int pid;
    private int qty;
    private String productname;
    private String modelDetails;
    private String pattern;
    private String styleType;
    private String weartype;
    private String styleCode;
    private String color;
    private String fabriccare;
    private String type;
    private String sleeve;
    private String necktype;
    private int pockets;
    private double price;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="catId")
    private Category category;
    public int getPid() {
        return pid;
    }
    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }
    public String getProductname() {
        return productname;
    }
    public String getModelDetails() {
        return modelDetails;
    }
    public String getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }
    public String getStyleType() {
        return styleType;
    }
    public String getWeartype() {
        return weartype;
    }
    public String getStyleCode() {
        return styleCode;
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public String getFabriccare() {
        return fabriccare;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public String getSleeve() {
        return sleeve;
    }
    public String getNecktype() {
        return necktype;
    }
    public int getPockets() {
        return pockets;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setPid(int pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }
    public void setQty(int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }
    public void setProductname(String productname) {
        this.productname = productname;
    }
    public void setModelDetails(String modelDetails) {
        this.modelDetails = modelDetails;
    }
    public void setPattern(String pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }
    public void setStyleType(String styleType) {
        this.styleType = styleType;
    }
    public void setWeartype(String weartype) {
        this.weartype = weartype;
    }
    public void setStyleCode(String styleCode) {
        this.styleCode = styleCode;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public void setFabriccare(String fabriccare) {
        this.fabriccare = fabriccare;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public void setSleeve(String sleeve) {
        this.sleeve = sleeve;
    }
    public void setNecktype(String necktype) {
        this.necktype = necktype;
    }
    public void setPockets(int pockets) {
        this.pockets = pockets;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }


}
```

Category model

```
   package com.project.model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int catId;
    private String idealfor;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="category")
    private List<Product> product;
    public int getCatId() {
        return catId;
    }
    public String getIdealfor() {
        return idealfor;
    }
    public List<Product> getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
    public void setCatId(int catId) {
        this.catId = catId;
    }
    public void setIdealfor(String idealfor) {
        this.idealfor = idealfor;
    }
    public void setProduct(List<Product> product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

}
```

Now i click on sell on Fashgen in the headear.jsp while clicking on that it displays this exception.I have check Many Solution for it but in the End i need help form you please get me out of this problem

I have added category entity too

Comment: Are you sure the category ids are correct and fetched properly? Your category id is not correct. Its in a wrong format and not a number.Can you also post your `Category` entity?

Comment: it seems to me that the (intended) expression "${c.id}" is not  "correctly" evaluated in the context of the jsp, but it is passed to controller as is "${c.id}" literally. I can only suggest to you to figure out why this take place.

Comment: I have added the category to the problem

Comment: sir @AbdullahKhan  I'm printing categories list in console the are fetched properly

Answer (score 0):

After i tested your code i came to realize that your category has not a proper setter for `catId` which is causing the problem

```
public void setCatId(int catid) {
    this.catId = catId; //This statement doesn't ever set the catId to catid
}
```

So in your `Category` class change your `setCatId` method to this

```
public void setCatId(int catid) {
    this.catId = catid; //Set catId to catid
}
```

**Note:** Always try to autogenerate setters/getters using IDE. In Eclipse `Source -> Generate Getters and Setters...`

---

**Update 1:**
Your getter also seem to be not in the proper format.
Update your getter to this

```
public int getCatId() { //Mind the camelCase name of this method
    return catId;
}
```

Comment: I Have done that through autogenerate setters/getters using spring IDE.

Comment: Bu that's not correct. `this.catId = catid;` is correct.

Comment: And by the way my eclipse is autogenerating the correct setters/getters. With the correct names.

Comment: AFTER DOING THAT SAME ERROR IS COMING.

Comment: the error is coming when you load the page or when you submit the form?

Comment: when i load the page

Comment: can  you update the question with the latest Category class?

Comment: I have done so many solution to it but there is no devlopment I have changed its Type ,Made aSeprate collection with model attribue then also

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything in the form bound to your catId field. There is a hidden "pid" field, and maybe that is supposed to be it?

```
<form:hidden path="pid" class="form-control" />
```

If that actually aligns with something I'm missing, then add a new spring binding for catId, otherwise, change that line to:

```
<form:hidden path="catId" class="form-control" />
```

This is pretty old, so maybe you've solved it by now, but this may help someone.

Having the proper getters and setters, as mentioned previously, is also very important.